# TYPO3: deleting page with huge number of records

Tags: typo3

I have problems removing a page via TYPO3 backend. It is most likely because it contains huge number of recordes stored on it. For example there is almost half milion of sys_file_reference stored on that page.
Is that possible to remove a TYPO3 page via CLI or so ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a CLI delete.

I would help TYPO3 in such a case with manual DB interactions as I assume manual deletion of this references by hand is impossible.

Do an update (= `set deleted= 1`) (or a real delete) on the table `sys_file_references` where you select on `tablenames`, `fieldname` and `uid_foreign`. In case of records in that table, which contain the sys_file_references you must build a bigger query with joins.

You also can try to go wild:
just 'delete' (= `set deleted= 1`) the page or the records with the references in a DB-query and let the scheduler task clean up.

as usual:
do a DB-backup before you work with records in this way.

---

1. identify the records
   `select uid from ???table??? where pid in (???page-uid-list???)`
2. identify the sys_file_references:
   `select * from sys_file_references where tablenames=???table??? and uid_foreign in ( "first select" )`
3. update/delete those identified records
   `update sys_file_references set deleted=0 where tablenames=???table??? and uid_foreign in ( "first select" )` /
   `delete from sys_file_references where tablenames=???table??? and uid_foreign in ( "first select" )`  **[1]**
4. delete those records (from 1) **in case of big numbers** (otherwise use BackEnd)
   `update ???table??? set deleted=1 where pid in (???page-uid-list???)` /
   `delete from ???table??? where pid in (???page-uid-list???)`
5. delete those pages
   `update pages set deleted=1 where uid in (???page-uid-list???)` /
   `delete from pages where uid in (???page-uid-list???)`
   or **delete from BackEnd**

**[1]**

```
UPDATE sys_file_references 
   SET deleted=0 
   WHERE tablenames=???table??? 
     AND uid_foreign IN (SELECT uid 
                           FROM ???table??? 
                          WHERE pid IN (???page-uid-list???)
                        )
```

Comment: I was thinkg about doing it that way but then when analyze what really happens when a page is beeing deleted I found out that for each record stored on the page there are actually three things happening: 
"copyMovedRecordToNewLocation"
"deleteVersionsForRecord"
"deleteRecord" (https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git/blob/72bf7473242e28357de3c7823158f3f60fb02f94:/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/DataHandling/DataHandler.php#l5119)
So I am not sure if there won't be any side effects if I just remove the records by mysql query ?

Comment: are the files linked to `pages` or to records on that page? do you use translations or workspaces/versions?

Comment: I can see that the relations are mostly to records on that page and on one other page. There are no workspaces/versions so it seems to be safe just to remove those records via sql - at least those records which are linked to records on same page, correct ?

Comment: see examples in my answer

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would write a CommandController, which makes use of DataHandler - expecting one parameter (id of a page) and deleting the page. Then you can call a CommandController via CLI. And watch new records in a sys_log table. The delete command of DataHandler triggers deleting of all subpages, content elements and filereferences (and hopefully also the versioning - didn't test this case yet). Make DB-backup before calling the command. And it might take quite a long time till everything is deleted.

Comment: That would be useful but it would have approximatelly same complexity as executing delete button via TYPO3 list or page module (process of deleting that page started via list/page module will take about 19 days - as I can see it is removing ~1 record per second - to finish so it would be probably same via command). Anyway thank you for proposal.

Answer (score 0):

You may find https://github.com/NamelessCoder/asynchronous_reference_indexing useful - it's a small package I created which delegates the indexing of references, which will happen when you delete pages and sys_file_references, so it doesn't happen in the same request.

While it doesn't truly solve the problem, it can usually bring the time it takes to execute the deletion request, below whichever threshold your server allows.